# Git repo setup for multiple dot net project

Tags: git, azure-devops

I have a dot net solution containing a WPF application, MS-SQL database, and 2 dlls.  Each is their own product in the sense that each can be shipped independently (dlls go to nuget to be consumed by other applications to talk to the database).  They are independant of each other but are developed in conjunction with one another (changes made in one typically results in changes in another).  The repos are used by VSTS build and release pipelines.

Should I set up a single git repo that contains all the projects or should i do a repo for each project?  Should I use submodules?  Are there any alternative solutions?

Comment: Could you indicate whether you solved the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was solved by having a separate project/solution for the DLL as it is used by multiple projects.  It has it's own life cycle and bug backlog.  Allowing work to be scoped and tracked for that common library and feature requests to be added to the backlog to extend is shared capability

Answer (score 2):

Only put a library in a separate repo when it is used in two different repos. If that is not the case then put the code in the same repo. Otherwise one could run into the anti-pattern nanoservices.